# Read variable from text file using JS

Tags: javascript, variables, text, set

in my program i have a variable

```
untangleGame.levels = 
[
 {
 "level" : 0,

 "circles" : [{"x" : 400, "y" : 156},
 {"x" : 381, "y" : 241},
 {"x" : 84, "y" : 233},
 {"x" : 88, "y" : 73}],

 "relationship" : {
 "0" : {"connectedPoints" : [1,2]},
 "1" : {"connectedPoints" : [0,3]},
 "2" : {"connectedPoints" : [0,3]},
 "3" : {"connectedPoints" : [1,2]}
 }
 },////////****** More Levels****///////


]
```

And i have to store this variable in text file. I created a function

```
function loadDoc() {
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/KB/canvasAts/levels.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) 
{
   untangleGame.levels = JSON. parse (client.responseText) ;
}
}
client.send();
}
```

Alert function shows the text, however the variable is still not set and i got error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" in line `var level = untangleGame.levels[untangleGame.currentLevel];`

Comment: 1st - there is no such line in code you have showed. 2nd - `client.responseText` and `untangleGame.levels` is text, not an array you trying to access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse text into JSON.

replace this line

```
untangleGame.levels = client.responseText;
```

with

```
untangleGame.levels = JSON.parse(client.responseText);
```

and you need to keep in earlier `if condition`

```
if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) 
{
  alert(client.responseText);
  untangleGame.levels = JSON. parse (client.responseText) ;
}
```

You are getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

because your value is not probably not populated yet if you are doing so outside that if-condition as client.responseText may be empty at that time.

Comment: I still get the same error. As i said, if i put `alert(client.responseText);` it shows me correct information, however if i write, for example, `alert(untangleGame.levels.circles[1].x);`, it shows me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

Comment: Tried, same. I'm not sure that i'm thinking in the right way. At this moment, i replaced `untangleGame.levels = [ ...]` with `untangleGame.levels = loadDoc();` , and the function is: `function loadDoc() {
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/KB/canvasAts/levels.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) 
{
   temp = JSON. parse (client.responseText) ;
}
}
client.send();
return temp;
}`  Sorry, it looks really messy in the comments..

Comment: You can't return from an asynchronous method. Update your method to show what you have tried so far to incorporate my suggestions.

Comment: @Unholyan after making changes suggested by me, what error do you get and on which line?

Comment: There were mistakes with the txt file - JSON couldn't read it. Inside the `loadDoc()` function `alert()` functions shows me the correct information. However, if I put `alert()` after calling `loadDoc()` function in the main function, it shows me error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. Variable untangleGame is declared globally.

Comment: I put my code in sourceforge: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5068 . In line 8 it shows me the correct info, and in line 92 it shows me an error.

Comment: @Unholyan because line 92 is executed before the ajax function has completed. Ajax being an asynch method, its callback method will be executed after the rest of the lines of current method is executed.

Comment: I left only `loadDoc():` in the `ready` function, and other functions are executed on the button click, so the txt document could load. Thank you very much for you help @gurvinder372 !

Comment: @Unholyan glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
loadDoc('/KB/canvasAts/levels.txt', function (response) {
    untangleGame.levels = JSON.parse(response) ;

});

function loadDoc(fileName, callback) {

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.overrideMimeType("application/json");
client.open('GET', fileName, true);
client.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == "200") {
        callback(client.responseText);
    }
};
  client.send(null);
}
```